# ASP.net lots of literals with same values?

Tags: c#, asp.net, literals, repeat

Given the code on the content page:

```
Are you sure you want to add another <asp:Literal runat="server" id="Name1" /> to the basket?  
You already have a <asp:Literal runat="server" id="Name2" /> in your basket.  
<asp:Literal runat="server" id="Name3" /> has not yet been added to your basket.
```

And then in the codebehind:

```
Name1.Text = Product.Name;
Name2.Text = Product.Name;
Name3.Text = Product.Name;
```

I'm pretty sure this isn't the greatest way to go about things, is there an ASP.net feature or a design pattern I'm unaware of?

Comment: I would "refactor" the sentences so I didn't actually need to repeat the product name 3 times. ;)

Comment: Seriously if I saw a program ask me that I'd post it on http://thedailywtf.com/

Comment: It's a bad example I know, but it's relevant if you have a multi panelled page

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why don't you use `string.Format`?

```
String.Format("Are you sure you want to add another {0} to the basket? You already have a {0} in your basket. {0} has not yet been added to your basket.", Product.Name)
```

Answer (score 3):

Well, in fact you don't need to use literals, if these three lines in your rendering should show the same product name, what about:

```
Are you sure you want to add another <%# Product.Name %> to the basket?  
You already have a <%# Product.Name %> in your basket.  
<%# Product.Name %> has not yet been added to your basket.
```

And during `Load` just call DataBind() in your `Page` or `Control`.

Or you can use a ResX, add a string resource called "BasketText" and put this string:

```
Are you sure you want to add another {0} to the basket?  
You already have a {0} in your basket.  
{0} has not yet been added to your basket.
```

And in your control or page, implement a internal or public read-only property called "BasketText" and in the getter do this:

```
return String.Format(GetLocalResourceObject("BasketText"), ProductName)
```

Then, your markup will look like this (*call DataBind too, as previous approach*):

```
<%# BasketText %>
```

---

**UPDATE & NOTE**

*Pay attention to other users suggesting inline evalutations `<%=...%>`. This is an old-style approach and it has strong counterparts. If you do this way and code modifies control collection, your page will throw an exception.*

*For that reason, I'll be always suggesting data-binding expressions, which doesn't have such problem and these work like a charm.*

Answer (score 1):

If you can reach the variable Product.name or expose it you can do this:

```
Are you sure you want to add another <%=Product.Name%> etc..
```

Instead of a literal

Answer (score 1):

Why dont you just use one Literal control and then use

```
String.format( "Are you sure you want to add another {0} to the basket?  You already have a {0} in your basket.  {0} has not yet been added to your basket.", Product.Name);
```

check it out:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1ksz8yb7.aspx

Cheers

Comment: ops, too late. but you shouldn't have theses strings hardcoded anyway

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a problem with this except the variable names could use some better names.  However you can dynamically add controls to your page, but that may be overkill for this situation.  Here's a good article on that.

https://web.archive.org/web/20211020131055/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/081402-1.aspx

Answer (score 0):

simply use only one literal with `runat="server"` and in the same place where you are currently assigning the `Product.Name` to those literals have a `String.Format`

Answer (score 0):

Can't say this is necessarily better, but a shorter alternative.

```
<%=string.Format("Are you sure you want to add another {0} to the basket?  You already have a {0} in your basket. {0} has not yet been added to your basket.",Product.Name)%>
```

Comment: I don't like this solution as it can produce an exception if control collection is modified in code.